# How to insert variable from HTML into array PHP and display array PHP back to HTML?

Tags: php, html, arrays

My array name in PHP is $OrderHistory.I try to make it auto-insert into array PHP whenever the customer click button "AddtoCart" and to display it back to HTML form,but it seem doesn't work. Any help will be much appreciated.

> Assume that there are variable from HTML that i'm gonna fetch it and put it array php, named $_POST['menu'] and $_POST['Quantity'];

```
if(isset($_POST['AddCart'])){
    if($_POST['menu']!= 0){

        if($_POST['Quantity'] != 0){
            $MName = $_POST['menu'];
            $MQuantity = $_POST['Quantity'];
            $OrderHistory = array($No => // $No Refers to number of order that customer made
                                        array(
                                         $Order => $MName,$MQuantity));

        }
    }
    $Count++; // $Count and $No are key that will show where the next menu and quantity goes in array.
    $No++;   
}
```

below this are where i'm gonna display back data inside array PHP to HTML that have been insert by customer.i try many ways but it only display number of key and quantity only.

```
    <td align=center><?=    ;?></td> // this will be display number of key array in php
    <td align=center><?=    ;?></td> // this will be display name of food
    <td align=center><?=    ;?></td> // this will be display quantity of food
```

Comment: I think it will be better if you use `SESSION`.

Comment: how to use it @MahbubulIslam ??..

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following. I used `GET` method here you can use `POST` method if you like.

```
<?php
// start session 
session_start();

// get the product id
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : "";
$quantity = isset($_GET['quantity']) ? $_GET['quantity'] : 1;

// make quantity a minimum of 1
$quantity=$quantity<=0 ? 1 : $quantity;

// add new item on array
$cart_item=array(
    'quantity'=>$quantity
);

/*
 * check if the 'cart' session array was created
 * if it is NOT, create the 'cart' session array
 */
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}

// check if the item is in the array, if it is, do not add
if(array_key_exists($id, $_SESSION['cart'])){
    // redirect to product list and tell the user it was added to cart
}

// else, add the item to the array
else{
    $_SESSION['cart'][$id]=$cart_item;

    // redirect to product list and tell the user it was added to cart
}
?>
```